# Magento checkout : By default on page load set Billing Information as the active accordion

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

On magento checkout page on load of page now the default active accordion is "Checkout Method" I want billing information as an active accordion on load.

I checked *accordion.js* file but did not get how to change on load of accordion.

[image]

This is Magento's default checkout

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via **overriding Modules First**. For the reference file see below.

Go to:

`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php`

change the line

`$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');`

to whatever order you desire

Important note: If you are using **Magento 1.7** version, these step codes are in

`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`

`protected function _getStepCodes()
    {
        return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
    }`

and change it as per your need.

I believe you may also need to change the steps as well in the javascript file

`skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`

It's better to create a new JS file in `default/default`.

You may require to do a lot of js and template changes to get what needed.

To **test the code** first, go to

`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`

and change function

```
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
        //return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review'); //default code commented

        return array('login', 'shipping', 'billing', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review'); //this will show shipping first and billing on the next step
}
```

Comment: Hi ! can you please tell me exact what steps i need to follow to get waht i need ?

Comment: Which version you are using ?

Comment: magento 1.8.1 version

Comment: I do not think so that only changing to Abstract.php file will open billing information accordion by default open on load.

Comment: You can specify your checkout steps load order by changing checkout steps codes.

Comment: As i do not want to change the order of accordion i want to open billing information accordion on load

Comment: Yes but how,that is what i am asking

Comment: Cart before horse issue, there are quote things set up from the Checkout Method screen save that need to be finished before you start beavering away on that billing screen. If you don't know the quote type, you have nothing to save billing address info to.